# When rotating video 90 degrees is there a difference between using the Rotate vs. Transform node?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm converting some iPhone portrait oriented videos to Image Sequences using Blender. I noticed Blender doesn't load my iPhone portrait videos correctly. They are displayed at a 90 degree angle. So I'm using the Compositing view to adjust the video and create a correct Image Sequence.

To rotate my videos I can both use the Transform node's Angle property or add a Rotate node. What is the best choice for rotating? The angle is exactly 90 degrees (or -90, depending on the source), so in theory that should be easy. So use the Transform node or the Rotate node?

Comment: whatever works? :) it looks like the transform node just incorporate the rotate node (both use NodeSocketFloatAngle), so if you only need to rotate you could use rotate for the sake of clarity